# Mac address for group owner WIFI DIRECT?

Tags: android, networking, wifi, android-wifi, wifi-direct

can I request for Mac address for group owner in WIFI DIRECT at android platform ??

i wounder if this correct ??

first request for `WifiP2pManager.GroupInfoListener`

 then it return `WifiP2pGroup` information.
from this there is `getOwner()` owner information, to get mac address there is `deviceAddress` from `WifiP2pDevice`.

can i get MAC address as the way above ?

Comment: You should try comparing the devices known MAC address (settings>hardware information, or something to that effect) with the one found using the method above. That would possibly have saved you asking this question?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is yes. Can't say much more, you have done all the work, you just have to try.
But later you should probably bother to get the IP address of the group owner instead of the MAC address.